# Hash-map returning null value for a key but key and value both exist in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have some HasMaps in a Util class. All are public static. I  have instantiated them by service layer. But problem is when i am using the get method to retrieve value for a key, it is returning null value. But if i am printing the entire map it is showing that both key and value exist.

**Util Class:**

```
public class Util_GetGeoCode
  {
    //divsion
//    public static Map<Integer,String> map_division_id = new HashMap();
    public static Map map_division_id = new HashMap();
    //district
    public static Map map_district_id = new HashMap();
    //upzilla
    public static Map map_upozila_id = new HashMap();
    //union
    public static Map map_uinon_id = new HashMap();

    public static void clear_all_maps()
      {
        //test

        System.out.println("clear Map");
        map_division_id.clear();
        map_district_id.clear();
        map_upozila_id.clear();
        map_uinon_id.clear();         
      }
  }//class
```

**Code where Map will be set :**

```
public class BeneficiarySyncManager extends SyncManager
{
    public void execute()
    {
        //other codes

        setAll_locations_geoCode_by_id(moswBeneList);
        System.out.println(" After setting Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id : "+Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id);
        Map m = Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id;
        System.out.println(" m (key) : "+m.keySet());
        System.out.println(" After get : "+Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id.get(3));


        //other codes

        //clear all the maps of id to geo code
        Util_GetGeoCode.clear_all_maps();
    }

    public void setAll_locations_geoCode_by_id(List list_moswBene)
      {
        //divsion
        Set set_division_id = new HashSet();
        //district
        Set set_district_id = new HashSet();
        //upzilla
        Set set_upozila_id = new HashSet();
        //union
        Set set_uinon_id = new HashSet();

          for (Iterator iterator = list_moswBene.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
            {
                Beneficiaries_Mosw next_Mosw = (Beneficiaries_Mosw) iterator.next();

                set_division_id.add(next_Mosw.getPresentDivisionId());
                set_division_id.add(next_Mosw.getPermanentDivisionId());

                set_district_id.add(next_Mosw.getPermanentDistrictId());
                set_district_id.add(next_Mosw.getPresentDistrictId());

                set_upozila_id.add(next_Mosw.getPermanentThanaUpazilaId());
                set_upozila_id.add(next_Mosw.getPresentThanaUpazilaId());

                set_uinon_id.add(next_Mosw.getPermanentUnionWardId());
                set_uinon_id.add(next_Mosw.getPresentUnionWardId());
            }//for (Iterator iterator = set_uinon_id.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)

          Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id   = sManager.service_getGeoCode_Divisions(set_division_id);
          Util_GetGeoCode.map_district_id   = sManager.service_getGeoCode_District(set_district_id);
          Util_GetGeoCode.map_upozila_id    = sManager.service_getGeoCode_Thana_Upazilas(set_upozila_id);
          Util_GetGeoCode.map_uinon_id      = sManager.service_getGeoCode_union_wards(set_uinon_id);

          //this line also prin null
          System.out.println(" inside set : Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id : "+Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id.get(3));
      }//public void setAll_locations_geoCode_by_id(List list_moswBene)
}//class
```

**out put:**

```
//other messages
inside set : Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id : null
 After setting Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id : {3=30}
 m (key) : [3]
 After get : null
```

But when i have tested, the same get method has worked. Below I have provided the test code with output.

**Test Code:**

```
 @Test
     public void test_getGeoCode_of_divisions()
       {
         BeneficiaryDao beneficiaryDao = new BeneficiaryDao();
         Set set_division_id = new HashSet();
         set_division_id.add(1);
         set_division_id.add(2);
         set_division_id.add(3);
         Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id = beneficiaryDao.dao_getGeoCode_Divisions(set_division_id);
         Map map_divGeoCodes = beneficiaryDao.dao_getGeoCode_Divisions(set_division_id);
         System.out.println("\n\nGeoCode of Divs : "+map_divGeoCodes);
         System.out.println(map_divGeoCodes.get(1));
         System.out.println("Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id : " +Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id.get(3));
         System.out.println("\n\n");
       }//public void test_getGeoCode_of_divisions()
```

**Test Out put:**
   GeoCode of Divs : {1=10, 2=20, 3=30}
   10
   Util_GetGeoCode.map_division_id : 30

Comment: Are you sure your `Map` contains the key `3` and not the key `"3"`? You are using raw types, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Eran  u may have seen, for surety i have printer the entire map.

Comment: That doesn't prove anything. printing an int that contains `3` will look exactly the same as printing a String that contains `"3"`.

Comment: Or perhaps you put `long` keys in your Map, which get boxed to `Long`, and when you try to find the key using an `int` literal, it gets boxed to an `Integer` and the key is not found.

Comment: This code is not good, and that is the precise reason that even a very small code issue is hard to find here. Use of util class to maintain public static maps (which are getting changed from outside) is a recipe for disasters. A 'solution' might help you here, but with this code, more problems would definitely raise their heads going forward.

Comment: you should step through the code in a debugger and check why get(3) returns null

Comment: Just a couple of points on the code. You are using an un-typed `Map` interfaces and this is bad practice as it allows you to add ANY object to it and is possibly the source of your issues. Also I'm not 100% sure that the way you obtain your `Iterator` object is correct. It's usually to obtain the iterator outside of the loop and use `while(iterator.hasNext())`

Comment: Also, the Java coding conventions/standards would be worth a read: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: Most probably a mismatch on the type of the key. Like the key may be string `3` and you're querying with int `3`. Not possible to tell without seeing how you fill the maps. Voting to close as you don't post all the relevant code.